# Android - Program ImageView Constraints in Custom Toast Class

Tags: java, android, imageview

**I have successfully add an ImageView to a CUSTOM TOAST VIEW GROUP.**

Right now that ImageView is horizontally centered in the bottom of the screen.

What I wish to do is to constraint this widget to the top of the screen and later put it some top margins. However I can't find the methods name that allows this to happen? Does it even exist? Is there a different solution to this scenario?

**How do I programmatically constraint this ImageView to the top of the toast view?**

```
public class CustomToast extends android.widget.Toast{

public CustomToast(String toast_text, Context toast_context, int toast_status) {
    super(toast_context);

    // TOAST
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(toast_context, toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    // VIEW
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();

    // BACKGROUND
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_toast);

    // IMAGE VIEW
    ImageView myImage = new ImageView(toast_context);
    myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_toast_valid);
    myImage.setMaxWidth(200);
    myImage.setMaxHeight(200);
    myImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    myImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    view.addView(myImage);

    // SHOW
    toast.show();
}
```

}

I have checked the **android documentation**, some **stackoverflow links** and even tried to find the method through the **Android Studio intelligent code completion**. So far I haven't been capable of solving this problem...

Answer (score 1):

In Android you have View and ViewGroups. 
The ViewGroups can contain childs, and this childs can be other View or ViewGroups.

The View have behave to himself (color, size, orientation...).
The ViewGroups have **order** behave to himself and his childs.

The most used ViewGroups are:

- FrameLayout
- LinearLayout
- RelativeLayout
- ConstraintLayout

Depending on your what you need you got to choose.

- FrameLayout order his child like a Stack of Views in the same way you
  are declaring in the xml.
- LinearLayout arranges other views either horizontally in a single
  column or vertically in a single row.
- RelativeLayout has references between childs to order.
- ConstraintLayout has "constraints" to order his childs, it is like
  RelativeLayout but most powerful.

In your implementation you have a "programmatically" implementation, maybe if you try to use the xml will be more simple.

Comment: I can´t use xml because I am using the view of a Custom Toast. These means the xml file "doesn't exist". . . But thank you for your answer 

Comment: Toast is not designed to appears in the top of the screen. Here you can find an example of Toast implementation.

https://uxdesign.cc/toasts-or-snack-bars-design-organic-system-notifications-1236f2883023

Comment: This Custom Toast Class is a fullscreen toast. Has you can see in the code I give it a background image (and other widgets that I removed to simplify the question). I am adding to this custom toast an Imageview and it is working. The ImageView is successfully added to the toast layout. I'm just not able to put it on the exact coordenates that I want. These coordenates are in the top of the custom toast view.

Comment: You are using a Toast like an Activity or Fragment, are mixing concepts and you are going to have this kind of problems.
Tip: NEVER think in coordenates in Android development.

Comment: You are completely right! I didn't want to say "coordinates". I wanted to say constraints. I think that I just invented a way to "fake constraint it". I am gone work on this and if successful I will post the "solution"... Anyways thank you for your answer, discussion and tip 